# Is it possible to reference image from another redmine case?

Tags: redmine

In a [Redmine](https://www.redmine.org/) case, it is possible to upload an image and have it displayed using the shorthand `!imagename.png!`.
I'd like to know if it is possible to reference an image from another case such that it is displayed in the case

Answer (score 1):

There is no shorthand syntax for that. You can however use the full URL path URL to the download of the attachment between the exclamation marks, such as

```
!/attachments/download/123/imagename.png!
```

You can get this path by right-clicking on the download link and using the "Copy link address" function (depending on your browser)

Comment: This was one of the first things I tried but unfortunately didn't work for me.

Comment: Redmine also checks the permissions of the current user when accessing the attachments. make sure that your current user as logged into the browser can see the issue where you uploded the attachment. If that look correct, we need details (e.g. what exactly the browser requests and what HTTP status the server  responds with)